# Increasing io.sort.mb

Tags: hadoop

It would be highly appreciated if someone could help me to find out what went wrong in my configuration.

I wanted to increase the value of io.sort.mb and thus I added the property below in core-site.xml.
     
        io.sort.mb
        350m

The runtime information I am attaching below clearly shows that the value of io.sort.mb, did not change rather the default value io.sort.mb = 100 stayed.

```
13/08/15 16:43:34 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@1e5e96c1
13/08/15 16:43:34 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
13/08/15 16:43:34 INFO mapred.MapTask: **io.sort.mb = 100**
13/08/15 16:43:34 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/08/15 16:43:34 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
13/08/15 16:43:34 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
13/08/15 16:43:34 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
13/08/15 16:43:34 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_004609_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
```

Since it was not working, I added the property in mapred-site.xml schema, however I got the same outcome as above.

Can anyone suggest me what should I do?

Thanking you in advance.

Haq

Comment: Where are you submitting the job from? What services were running on the node where you made the change to `mapred-site.xml`?

Comment: Thanks a million for your attention. My project is querying big data, RDF data, to be precise. I am using a repository which essentially perform the job submission task. One important note, I have only one node in my cluster.

Comment: Your 'repository' node where you're performing the submission from - does it have hadoop installed, and this value configured in it's config file?

Comment: Chris, Yes, hadoop is installed in my repository node. I have only one node anyway.

Answer (score 1):

according to the article [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/configuration-parameters-what-can-you-just-ignore/) io.sort.mb should be 10 * io.sort.factor incase you have ram.
"core-site.xml"

```
<property>
<name>io.sort.factor</name>
<value>100</value>
<description>More streams merged at once while sorting files.</description>
</property>  

<property>
<name>io.sort.mb</name>
<value>200</value>
<description>Higher memory-limit while sorting data.</description>
</property>
```

trying changing sort factor also on all nodes.

Comment: Thanks Peter! That was very useful suggestion. I read the tips provided by the Cloudera sites but certainly missed this link you have given. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

this conf should be in mapred-site.xml instead of core-site.xml

refer: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred-default.html